# javascript loop to change the display of each element by clicking on it

Tags: javascript

I am really new at JavaScript and now i'm kinda struggling with this problem... My JavaScript code is really repetitive and i would like to make it shorter and more readible... (I heard that using a loop could shorten my code but i don't really know how to do that...) could you help with me that ??

The goal is that i would like to display the selected element in the display area (and then, hide all the other elements that were not selected). I don't know if it makes sense ??

So there is my script:

```
const hair1 = document.querySelector('.AAAAB');
const hair2 = document.querySelector('.AAAAC');
const hair3 = document.querySelector('.AAAAD');
const hair4 = document.querySelector('.BBBBA');
const hair5 = document.querySelector('.BBBBC');
const hair6 = document.querySelector('.BBBBD');

function handleRadioClick() {
  hairBlack.style.display = 'none';
  if (document.querySelector('input[name="hairstyle"]:checked').value === "A" && 
  document.querySelector('input[name="haircolor"]:checked').value === "A") {
      hair1.style.display = 'block';
      hair2.style.display = 'none';
      hair3.style.display = 'none';
      hair4.style.display = 'none';
      hair5.style.display = 'none';
      hair6.style.display = 'none';

      console.log('checked 1');

  } else if (document.querySelector('input[name="hairstyle"]:checked').value === "A" && 
  document.querySelector('input[name="haircolor"]:checked').value === "B") {
      hair1.style.display = 'none';
      hair2.style.display = 'block';
      hair3.style.display = 'none';
      hair4.style.display = 'none';
      hair5.style.display = 'none';
      hair6.style.display = 'none';
    
    console.log('checked 2');
  } else if (document.querySelector('input[name="hairstyle"]:checked').value === "A" && 
  document.querySelector('input[name="haircolor"]:checked').value === "C") {
      hair1.style.display = 'none';
      hair2.style.display = 'none';
      hair3.style.display = 'block';
      hair4.style.display = 'none';
      hair5.style.display = 'none';
      hair6.style.display = 'none';

    console.log('checked 3');  

  } else if (document.querySelector('input[name="hairstyle"]:checked').value === "B" && 
  document.querySelector('input[name="haircolor"]:checked').value === "A") {
      hair1.style.display = 'none';
      hair2.style.display = 'none';
      hair3.style.display = 'none';
      hair4.style.display = 'block';
      hair5.style.display = 'none';
      hair6.style.display = 'none';

    console.log('checked 4');
    
  } else if (document.querySelector('input[name="hairstyle"]:checked').value === "B" && 
  document.querySelector('input[name="haircolor"]:checked').value === "B") {
      hair1.style.display = 'none';
      hair2.style.display = 'none';
      hair3.style.display = 'none';
      hair4.style.display = 'none';
      hair5.style.display = 'block';
      hair6.style.display = 'none';

    console.log('checked 5');
  
  } else if (document.querySelector('input[name="hairstyle"]:checked').value === "B" && 
  document.querySelector('input[name="haircolor"]:checked').value === "C") {
      hair1.style.display = 'none';
      hair2.style.display = 'none';
      hair3.style.display = 'none';
      hair4.style.display = 'none';
      hair5.style.display = 'none';
      hair6.style.display = 'block';

      console.log('checked 6');

  } else {
    console.log('checked');
  }
}

const colorButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="haircolor"]');
colorButtons.forEach(color => {
    color.addEventListener('click', handleRadioClick);
});
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <section class="menu">
            <input type="radio" id="hairstyle" name="category" value="A" checked="checked"><label for="hairstyle">HAIR</label>
            <input type="radio" id="haircolor" name="category" value="B"><label for="haircolor">COLOR</label>
        </section>

        <section class="categories">
            <section class="hairstyles">
                <section class="hairstyles-black" id="hairstyles-black">
                    <input type="radio" id="hairstyle-1" name="hairstyle" value="A" checked="checked"><label for="hairstyle-1"><img
                        src="img/hairstyle-1.png" alt="hairstyle-1"></label>
                    <input type="radio" id="hairstyle-2" name="hairstyle" value="B"><label for="hairstyle-2"><img
                        src="img/hairstyle-2.png" alt="hairstyle-2"></label>
                </section>
                

                <section class="hairstyle-color-1" id="hairstyle-color-1">
                    <input type="radio" id="haircolor-1-1" name="hairstyle" value="1"><label
                        for="haircolor-1-1"><img src="img/haircolor-1.png" alt="haircolor-1-1"></label>
                    <input type="radio" id="haircolor-1-2" name="hairstyle" value="2"><label
                        for="haircolor-1-2"><img src="img/haircolor-6.png" alt="haircolor-1-2"></label>
                </section>

                <section class="hairstyle-color-2" id="hairstyle-color-2">
                    <input type="radio" id="haircolor-2-1" name="hairstyle" value="3"><label
                        for="haircolor-2-1"><img src="img/haircolor-2.png" alt="haircolor-1-1"></label>
                    <input type="radio" id="haircolor-2-2" name="hairstyle" value="4"><label
                        for="haircolor-2-2"><img src="img/haircolor-7.png" alt="haircolor-1-2"></label>
                </section>

                <section class="hairstyle-color-3" id="hairstyle-color-3">
                    <input type="radio" id="haircolor-3-1" name="hairstyle" value="5"><label
                        for="haircolor-3-1"><img src="img/haircolor-3.png" alt="haircolor-3-1"></label>
                    <input type="radio" id="haircolor-3-2" name="hairstyle" value="6"><label
                        for="haircolor-3-2"><img src="img/haircolor-8.png" alt="haircolor-3-2"></label>
                </section>
            </section>


            <section class="haircolors" id="haircolors">
                <input type="radio" id="haircolor-1" name="haircolor" value="A"><label for="haircolor-1"><img
                        src="img/color-1.png" alt="haircolor-1"></label>
                <input type="radio" id="haircolor-2" name="haircolor" value="B"><label for="haircolor-2"><img
                        src="img/color-2.png" alt="haircolor-2"></label>
                <input type="radio" id="haircolor-3" name="haircolor" value="C"><label for="haircolor-3"><img
                        src="img/color-3.png" alt="haircolor-3"></label>
            </section>

        </section>

        <div class="display" id="display">
            <img class="AAAAA" src="img/AAAAA.png" alt="">
            <img class="AAAAB" src="img/AAAAB.png" alt="">
            <img class="AAAAC" src="img/AAAAC.png" alt="">
            <img class="AAAAD" src="img/AAAAD.png" alt="">
            <img class="BBBBB" src="img/BBBBB.png" alt="">
            <img class="BBBBA" src="img/BBBBA.png" alt="">
            <img class="BBBBC" src="img/BBBBC.png" alt="">
            <img class="BBBBD" src="img/BBBBD.png" alt="">
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is the first time posting here ! Please be nice to me haha ! Thank you very much !

Comment: This code seems to have a lot of bugs, can you post it on JSFiddle and get it working there? Once it fully works, you can ask for a code review. One thing you are missing is that `addEventListener` can pass an `event` which contains the button that was clicked. It could look like this: `btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => handleRadioClick(e));`. Now your function `handleRadioClick` knows which radio button was clicked.

Comment: `btn.addEventListener('click', handleRadioClick);` does exactly the same thing as `btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => handleRadioClick(e));`. OP just needs to add a parameter to the function: `function handleRadioClick(e) {`...

Comment: @Kokodoko Thank you for your reply ! Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/learningApa/7nfe89r4/9) !

Comment: @RoToRa I am really sorry, I'm really really new at JS and i didn't understand the "OP just needs to add a parameter to the function" part. Could you explain that to me please ?